# Need clarification Rebuild Registry instructions

Tags: drush

From the module page:

1. You can just drush dl registry_rebuild and drush will download it
   into your .drush folder. (Alternately, you can obtain the package
   another way and copy the folder into .drush yourself.)

----I have no drush folder that I am aware of, I am using Xampp on a different drive (E:), using the built in Drush from Aquia Desktop on C: drive, not clear about that step.

2. On a multisite install, cd into the site you're rebuilding, as in cd
   sites/mymultisite**strong text**

---- This is not a multisite, so what command should I use?

I followed the steps and it seems like it worked by showing success, however, the site still has errors, like it didn't work....

Did this actually work? Any way to check in logs or something?

[image: Drush Registry rebuild settings]

Comment: It appears to have run fine as you say - maybe whatever problem you're having isn't fixed by rebuilding the registry

Comment: 1. It's displayed in your CLI already, " Project registry_rebuild ... downloaded to C:something". So thats where it resides and .drush/ is a hidden folder. 2. As Clive said, no errors were reported during `drush rr` so maybe the errors are caused by a diff. issur. You can also post the error message. :)